# How to add order by column name after define the query in linq, when your linq have two data to be selected?

Tags: c#, linq

I intend to add order by column name after define the query, but in the query set have two dataset to be retrieve, the below is my queryset

```
var query = (from data in entities.transaction_table 
             join data2 in entities.vendor_table 
               on data.vendor_id equals data2.user_id 
            where data.user_id == user.user_id 
           select new { data, data2 });


//SORT
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
{
    query = query.OrderBy("" +sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
}
```

when i try to execute query, the sort column does not found because i select data and data2.

```
{"No property or field 'date_created' exists in type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2'"}
```

how can i execute this query with specific order by column

- if i use select data instead of select new data, data2, the query was a success, however i need to retrieve data on both side

Comment: `...select new { data, data2, date_created}`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko nice try, but i not only need to sort based on date_created, i was going to sort by entire column in the 'data' and data2 fieldset

Comment: What is `date_created`? Is it `data.date_created` or `data2.date_created`?